# Filenames with umlaute in a user interface

Tags: python, unicode

I have a problem with unicode in python. I wish I could give a good code example here, but I don't know how to display it. Specifically it is about a blender 3d add-on.

In this add-on I want to list the filenames of a folder in an enumerator property. This works fine, but the umlauts are just not displayed correctly. Strangely enough, the names that are not displayed correctly in the property are displayed absolutely correctly in the console using print().

Then I thought: In this case the problem must lie with the program. But that is not the case either. I then manually made a list with many äöü in it, which could be displayed without problems in the enumerator.

Here is the relevant code part I use:

```
# get files with path
p = Path(directory).glob('*.py')
files_with_path = [f for f in p if f.is_file()]
# isolate names
files = [Path(f).stem for f in files_with_path]
# replace underlines with empty space for UI
files_UI = [f.replace('_',' ') for f in files]
    
# create list to return (needed: index number, name, description)
EnumItems = []
for f in files_UI:
    IndexNumb = files_UI.index(f)
    EnumItems.append((str(IndexNumb),str(f),'Render Presets'))
```

The names in the console:

[image]

The names in the UI:

[image]

I'm working on Windows 10 with Visual Studio Code. The files are written with the pathlib module.

Comment: Where do you print the file in your code? Are you sure you are using the code you included in the question? `... and print(type(f))` (what?). I assume you are in Windows (right?) so you should give us which functions you are using to print and create filenames. Windows has different API with different encodings

Comment: maybe simply program use font which doesn't have these chars. Or maybe it doesn't use encoding `utf-8`